# Proof that W is a subspace of V vectorial space

Tags: linear-algebra, self-learning

Let $ V = \mathbb{R}^3 $, considering $ W = \{ (x,y,z) \in V: x \leq y \leq z \} $. Is W a subspace of V?

To proof that I have to demonstrate:

1) W is nonempty, that means $W \ne \emptyset$
2) if $ x \in W$ and $ y \in W$, then $x+y \in W$
3) if $\alpha \in \mathbb{C}$ and $x \in W$, then $\alpha x \in W$

I don't know how to proof that using the inequalities above.
How can I apply the three conditions?

Comment: 1. Find something that's in $W$. 2. Take two arbitrary things in $W$, and show that their sum is in $W$. 3. Take an arbitary thing in $W$ and an arbitrary scalar in $\mathbb{C}$, and show that their product is in $W$. You will find the latter difficult.

Comment: @user3482749 I have the idea that for some $\alpha < 0 $ will change my inequalities of x,y,z. The problem to me is to understand how works the other proofs using the inequalities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are asking how you would show each of these, typically the way one shows a purported subspace is not empty is the show that (0, 0, 0) is in the sunset.  Certainly it is true that $0\le 0\le 0$.  To show that "if (a, b, c) and (x, y, z) are in the set then (a+ x, b+ y, c+ z) is in the set" argue that "if (a, b, c) is in the set then $a\le b\le c$ and if (x, y, z) is in the set then $x\le y\le z$.  So $a+ x\le b+ x$ and $b+ x\le b+ y$.  Therefore $a+ x\le b+ y$.  Also $b+ y\le c+ y$ and $c+ y\le c+ z$ so $b+ y\le c+ z$.  Together they say that $a+ x\le b+ y\le c+ z$ which shows that (a+ x, b+ y, c+ z) is in the set.

As you seem to recognize, it is the third one "if $\alpha\in C$ and $x\in W$ then $\alpha X\in W$" is NOT true.  You also realize that is is not true for $\alpha$ negative.

To prove that general statement is NOT true, it is sufficient to give a "counter example"- a single example where the statement is not true.  In this case, as "mathcounterexamples.net" says, taking $\alpha= -1$ is sufficient.  With $\alpha= -1$ and $X= (1, 2, 3)$ so that $x\le y\le z$ then $\alpha X= -1(1, 2, 3)= (-1, -2, -3)$ but $-1\le -2\le -3$ is NOT true.

Answer (score 2):

$W$ is not a subspace. $(1,2,3) \in W$ but $-(1,2,3) = (-1,-2,-3) \notin W$.